# How to decrypt a video file and play it in react native?

Tags: react-native, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

How to decrypt a video file which has been encrypted in AES 128 encryption and play it from memory stream without saving the file locally...
I have come across some libraries which decrypts text but not video file directly...
So I have to convert the video to byte array or similar and then play it from the memory stream...
I couldn't find answers for react native...while there is some for native android... and in java/c#...
I am using javascript so, unable to find references which would help...